# Swagger 2.0 Implementation in spring MVC rest api

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger

I am looking for help on implementing swagger in my spring MVC rest api. I tried googling but so much confusion that I am not able to understand. I am not using spring boot.

Answer (score 3):

**Changes to Configuration class**

```
package com.sample.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

/**
 * @author EOV537 -
 * @since 1.0
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sample"})
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX = "/WEB-INF/jsp/";

    private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX = ".jsp";

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        // viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceViewResolver.class); // NOSONAR
        viewResolver.setPrefix(VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX);

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

**WebApplint**

```
package com.sample.config;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

/**
 * @author EOV537 -
 * @since 1.0
 */
public class WebApplint implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer#onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext)
     */

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = null;

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "web");

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class, SwaggerConfig.class);

        // Manages the lifecycle
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextCleanupListener());

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic springWebMvc = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet",
                new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        springWebMvc.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        springWebMvc.addMapping("/");
        springWebMvc.setAsyncSupported(true);

    }

    @PreDestroy
    protected final void cleanup() {
        if (rootContext != null) {
            rootContext.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
package com.sample.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

/**
 * @author EOV537 -
 * @since 1.0
 */
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("My REST API", "Some custom description of API.", "API Blog web",
                "Terms of service", "myeaddress@company.com", "License of API", "API license URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }

}
```

**Add following 2 dependencies in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Access Swagger using

> http://localhost:8082/rest-service/swagger-ui.html#/

Comment: In your class SwaggerConfig this line in you example is incorrect: .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build(); it should be: .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().apiInfo(apiInfo());